# 403 Forbidden Error LEMP

Tags: permissions, nginx

I have a nginx server running with a wordpress and Ajenti setup working like a champ. As well as gitlab and owncloud which both work, just not used.

But when I try to access a new setup, opencart, it gives me a 403 forbidden error.

I have the root folder in the same place as my other folders, and have even chmod777 the actual folder to attempt to get it to work with no success.

Error :

```
2015/06/12 07:59:48 [error] 19784#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/opencart/" is forbidden, client: 76.164.165.4, server: adminpanelz.us.to, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "adminpanelz.us.to:9000"
2015/06/12 07:59:48 [error] 19784#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/opencart/" is forbidden, client: 76.164.165.4, server: adminpanelz.us.to, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "adminpanelz.us.to:9000"
2015/06/12 07:59:49 [error] 19784#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/opencart/" is forbidden, client: 76.164.165.4, server: adminpanelz.us.to, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "adminpanelz.us.to:9000"
2015/06/12 07:59:49 [error] 19784#0: *4 directory index of "/var/www/opencart/" is forbidden, client: 76.164.165.4, server: adminpanelz.us.to, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "adminpanelz.us.to:9000"
```

The setup I was following was here : http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2015/01/How-to-setup-Opencart-with-Nginx-and-MySql/How-to-setup-opencart-with-nginx-and-mysql/

Comment: Is there anything inside the `/var/www/opencart` folder? Like e.g. a file `index.php`? Otherwise, the server will try to serve a directory listing, which it isn't allowed, so it issues a 403 instead.

Comment: Yes, there is a single info.php file, as i was just following the tutorial

Comment: Can you retrieve the file info.php by name? As in: http://example.com/info.php?

Comment: Jos.. i feel so stupid now.. thank you If you want to answer the question ill do the little answered thingy so you can get the credit :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser requests a URL from the server that is not really a file but a directory, like `http://example.com`, the server looks in the directory for a file like `index.htm`, `index.html`, `index.php` and maybe others. If it can't find such a file, it may serve a "directory listing" instead, if you allow it. Otherwise, it will issue a 403 error.

`info.php` is not one of the files that can be served as default. So if you want to retrieve `info.php` you will have to call that by its full name.

Comment: Haha, thankies. I've had so many issues recently since I'm trying to install so much stuff on one server I just assumed that it was something that broke